# Amazon Cloud Watch Graphs - Library offering similar graphs?

Tags: javascript, html, graph

When reviewing data in AWS Cloud Watch, the line charts allow you to select an area, and then it zooms into that section of the chart.  Are there any charts, html5, jQuery, that offer something similar?

Example:
[image: Zoomed Out]
[image: Highlighting]
[image: Zoomed in]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This maybe a little late, but others may find it useful.

Cloudwatch uses a javascript package called flot: http://www.flotcharts.org/

There is even a specific example of the functionality you're looking for: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/selection/index.html

Comment: Nice! Yes, too late for the project I had in mind when I asked. But, still thanks for the link. I am surprised I didn't come across this when looking for charting options.